# Pump running even if relay says "off"

Tags: relay

I have a relay that should be switched off when the analog value is too high by the Arduino code:

```
int digitalPin = 4; // for the relay
int analogPin = A0; // for the soil moisture sensor
int digitalVal; // digital readings
int analogVal; // analog readings

void setup()
{
    pinMode(digitalPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(digitalPin, LOW);
    Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
    analogVal = analogRead(analogPin); // read the value returned by the soil moisture sensor
    if (analogVal < 400) { // if the soil moisture sensor returns a value < 400
        digitalWrite(digitalPin, HIGH); // The water pump waters the plant
    } else {
        digitalWrite(digitalPin, LOW); // The water pump stops watering
    }
    Serial.println(analogVal);
    delay(100);
}
```

But, as you can see [on the video](https://youtu.be/on5L21li6Ro), despite going above the 400 threshold, having the relay pin switching off, it continues to pump.

Here is my architecture:

[image]

I just changed the relay to [an Elegoo 4](https://www.elegoo.com/en-fr/products/elegoo-8-channel-relay-module-kit):

[image]

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.robotique.tech/tutoriel/systeme-darrosage-automatique-avec-arduino/).

Comment: you have to connect the relay to the controlled pin

Comment: don't use the arduino as a power supply for the motor ... it could destroy the arduino

Comment: Oh, right @jsotola but isn't it what I did? (I just uploaded a photo of my attempt to implement the sketch)
Thanks for the tip for the power supply. I will look for one when I will be sure my thing is working properly :)

Comment: `isn't it what I did?` ... no, the wiring diagram shows otherwise

Comment: Oh, you mean that the green and the light blue wires should be the same? So the relay would be connected to the control pin ?

Comment: "I will look for one when I will be sure my thing is working properly :) " Sounds like the chicken and egg thing. Expensive if the arduino fails. Note: "A Power Supply the Arduino is NOT!" A mistook could also take out your computer.

Comment: `you mean that the green and the light blue wires should be the same?` ... no ... your code shows the control pin to be pin 4 ... your wiring diagram show a connection at pin 2

Comment: yes, I think that's a mistake from the tutorial @jsotola as [the video accompanying it](https://youtu.be/ZI2cPHAi5dw?t=49) says to connect the (S) pin of the relay to pin4 of the Arduino

Comment: why are you posting inaccurate material? ... there is no reason why anyone should have to watch a video to learn what you are doing ... questions should be self contained  without need for external links

Comment: hmm, I think I've posted the inaccurate material because it is the context of the question @jsotola    My question is about the pump working continuously while the relays should stop it at some point

Comment: Do you hear the relais switch? Its PCB has an LED, does it reflect the expected state? Only if that is correct, you should think about adding the pump.

Comment: Can you post your connection diagram? A hand-drawn document is better than the wrong diagram in the question.